# Can I apply for a Schengen visa from the UK if I am on a tier 5 temporary workers visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens

I am traveling to the UK on a tier 5 religious workers visa and wish to apply for a Schengen visa to visit Portugal, Germany and France. I am a permanent resident in New Zealand and will be traveling on my South African passport. Am I able to apply for the Schengen visa from the UK? It says on most websites that you have to be a resident of the UK, however I am not sure whether having this religious workers visa classes me as a resident? It is valid for 24 months.

Comment: So the question is really - does the tier 5 visa class you as a resident? If so, then you can apply for one from in the UK, and if not, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Since Tier 5 [does not afford](http://www.tier12345.co.uk/tier-5-five.php) automatically any benefits of permanent residence in the UK, you will have to find out if you are resident currently or not.

To answer the question [if you are resident](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/international/residence.htm) in the UK is tricky. Until April of 2013, this was a question if you stay above 183 a year in the UK, or, if not, if you come to the UK to live or work on a continuing basis. Issues if your family etc, are in the UK also matter. Since then, there is a temporary [new method to test](http://tools.hmrc.gov.uk/rift) (click the link on the bottom) if you are a resident.

All those tests basically check if you have to pay taxes in the UK. This, in return, determines if you are resident.

Comment: This answer incorrectly conflates the concepts of residence as an immigration status with residence for purposes of taxation.